# cmd.exe not incrementing number in for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've been going around in circles for over an hour now, anyone tell me why this isn't working please?

I need to create an array of folders and with that array fire off a robocopy command

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set str=%USERPROFILE%
set server=\\poppy
call set mod=%%str:C:=%server%%%
if not exist "%mod%" mkdir %mod%
set list= %mod%\Documents %mod%\Downloads
set counter=0
(for %%a in (%list%) do (
    echo.%%a
    set counter=counter+1
    echo.%counter%
))
pause
```

No matter what i try i can't increment the counter :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "str=%USERPROFILE%"
set "server=\\poppy"
call set "mod=%%str:C:=%server%%%"
if not exist "%mod%" mkdir %mod%
set "list= %mod%\Documents %mod%\Downloads"
set counter=0
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(for %%a in (%list%) do (
    echo.%%a
    set /a counter=counter+1
    echo.!counter!
))
endlocal
pause
```

For more information check this - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx

For arithmetical with `SET`  you need `/A` switch.

Comment: you're a diamond, i've been going backwards and forwards using the /A switch and ! around the variable. Obviously i didn't have the right combination.